# Window tearing while recording any window with any screen recording software

Tags: graphics, xorg, display-resolution, desktop-recording

So i was recording my screen while writing some code on Vs Code but i when i reviewed my recorded my video , i found huge window tearing in my video but I didn't see any window or screen tearing on my screen while recording the video.

I have tried recording my video at different frame rates and different resolutions but all of them have the same problem. Here's the link to the footage which shows this problem.
[Link to video](https://youtu.be/-ubVZXDQSq8)

Here is the intel.conf file configuration from /usr/share/X11/Xorg.conf/

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
    Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option      "DRI"    "true"
    Option      "TearFree"  "true"
    Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

I face this window-tearing every time i open any window. This problem doesn't occur while recording my Desktop.

What can I do to solve this issue? All help is appreciated.